# Best practice for shipping iOS library that links against Apple (Accelerate) framework

Tags: ios, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I've written in C++ static .a library that links accelerate framework.

I've written an ObjC consumer project to demonstrate this library. The consumer also needs to link Accelerate framework! (I wasn't expecting this).

Is there some way of packaging my library a little more professionally so that I don't require consumers to manually link Accelerate framework?

I suppose I could dynamic link?  Every iOS device will have Accelerate...

I was kind of hoping to build process might pull out the bits it needed to build my .a.

Is there a ***"best practice"***?

Answer (score 1):

no. the main app must link the dylibs. an archive is just an 'dumb' archive

what might be professional (IMO) is a cocoapod